# Is there a way to add a "Copy to clipboard" button in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs, copy-paste

I have a Google Doc that has a bunch of templates that I need to copy and then paste somewhere else. I'm wondering if Google Docs has a function that lets me highlight a paragraph then add a "Copy to clipboard" button somewhere near it, which copies that body of text.

If not, is there a button I can add which at least highlights some particular text?

Comment: why not use ctrl+c ?

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER Thats what I do now, but I copy 40+ templates per hour so having a copy button will save time

Comment: you can use https://www.autohotkey.com/ to remap unused key on your keyboard or mice to act like ctrl+c

Comment: @user0 I think Autohotkey is only for Microsoft's Windows (but simmilar tools available for other windowing systems). And even with the best setup e.g. X-Windows's select and paste(bound to middle mouse button). You will still have to do the select.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Apps Script to add a custom menu with your button or an option to open a sidebar/dialog that holds your button.

You can even publish your script as an add-on so the button will be available on all your Google Documents files.